# Isolating scala non-cross-published library in separate module within a multi module project in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

Kind of an annoying issue but there is a scala library I needed for a large project that is only published for `2.12`. Ideally, I would isolate this library into it's own module as to not force the entire project to be in scala `2.12` as, ultimately, this project will need to be in scala3. Is there a way to have a multi-module sbt project that would allow a scala 2.12 project to depend on a scala3 project or co-exist alongside different scala versions?

This is roughly what I have so far (the example below I am actually using `2.13.8` but the idea should be the same):

```
lazy val scala213 = "2.13.8"
lazy val scala212 = "2.12.15"

lazy val supportedScalaVersions = List(scala212, scala213)

val Versions = 
  new {
    val parser = "9.0.20210312"
    val catseffect = "3.3.3"
}

val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalacOptions -= "-Xfatal-warnings"
)

def full(p: Project) = p % "test->test;compile->compile"

lazy val cypherparser = (project in file("modules/cypherparser"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := scala212,
    crossScalaVersions := supportedScalaVersions,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.opencypher" % "parser-9.0" % Versions.parser
    )
  ).dependsOn(shared)

lazy val shared = (project in file("modules/shared"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := scala213,
    crossScalaVersions := supportedScalaVersions,
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % Versions.catseffect,
      "org.typelevel" %% "munit-cats-effect-3" % "1.0.7" % Test,
    )
  )

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(shared, cypherparser)
  .settings(
    crossScalaVersions := Nil,
    publish / skip := false
  )
```

Running the above I get

```
sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading shared:shared_2.12:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: You can have two independent modules with different **Scala** versions. But you can't make one of them to depend on the another, for the very same reason you can't depend on a library that used `2.12` in a `2.13` codebase.

Comment: Thanks - alright that more or less confirms my fears.  I was hoping there would be a way to cross-build the module depended on by the `2.12` (e.g. `2.12` and `2.13`)  module to allow interoperability but from your answer and some experimentation, this does not appear to be possible.

Comment: Wait, you do can cross-compile `shared` to both `2.12` & `2.13` that way `cypherparser` can depend on the `2.12` version of `shared` - My question then would be why even cross-compile `shared` to `2.13`?

Comment: To be honest, at this point it's _mostly_ just an exercise. However, this project will eventually grow to be pretty large and I didn't want to constrain the `scalaVersion` to be `2.12` just for this one library. This project is weird in that there will be a common algebra and domain objects used by modules of the library above (`2.12`) and another module that will have C-binding library dependency only written for scala3 :/. If I cross-build `shared` for `2.13` I should be able to use it in both `2.12` and `scala3` modules, right?

Comment: You may ask in the [**discord** server](https://discord.gg/QffNwKdb), for all I can see your code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

So following the comments discussion, I decided it would be worthwhile to cross-build my shared module so that `cypherparser` could depend on it. It turns out to be pretty wonky to do this using sbt, however I discovered the `sbt-projectmatrix` plugin and with a bit of experimentation using the following

```
ThisBuild / version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val scala213 = "2.13.8"
lazy val scala212 = "2.12.15"

val Versions = 
  new {
    val parser = "9.0.20210312"
    val catseffect = "3.3.3"
}

val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalacOptions -= "-Xfatal-warnings"
)

def full(p: Project) = p % "test->test;compile->compile"

lazy val cypherparser = (projectMatrix in file("modules/cypherparser"))
  .dependsOn(shared)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.opencypher" % "parser-9.0" % Versions.parser
    )
  )
  .jvmPlatform(scalaVersions = Seq(scala212))

lazy val shared = (projectMatrix in file("modules/shared"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % Versions.catseffect,
      "org.typelevel" %% "munit-cats-effect-3" % "1.0.7" % Test,
    )
  )
  .jvmPlatform(scalaVersions = Seq(scala212, scala213))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  // .aggregate(cypherparser)
  .aggregate(shared.projectRefs ++ cypherparser.projectRefs: _*)
  .settings(
    publish / skip := false
  )
```

... I can depend on `shared` as I would like. Magically, I can also `aggregate` these modules with different versions as well (still not quite sure how/why this works, I just followed the documentation). Note: you cannot use `scalaVersion` in the settings else this breaks things -- only declare scala versions within the `platform` declaration.